# How to make sure all incoming requests are properly executed?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I have a Node JS / Express app that receive periodic requests to update some values in my database (MongoDb).

The problem is when my app receive too much request in a very tiny timelapse, the app acts weird and not all requests are executed. For example when It receive 400 requests in 10 minutes, some of them fail, but the same amount of reqs in 40-60 minutes give me a 100% of successful requests.

My app is hosted on heroku and according to my metrics, my dyno is not running out of memory. So I don't understand what's wrong with my failure rate increasing when I decrease the timelapse.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: problem seems to be with cpu usage and not memory since its a single threaded app.

Comment: Check your heroku logs and notice the logs from heroku's dyno manager showing info on request url, response size, status code, etc. Your status code might be something related to the issue